# Help with Flow Mania

Tags: grid-deduction

[image: Flow Mania, level 116]

I've tried to cover all squares, but I can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start somewhere, think about

> how the yellow and purple lines can avoid each other.

Complete solution:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

> You can see that the white line must go left, because otherwise it partitions the purple dots, or the purple line must partition the cyan dots, and to the end because otherwise the white line partitions the red dots.